# When will memory be deleted in singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have seen standard(most of the people using this) singleton design pattern, but here I got confused when the memory will be deleted.

do we have to write static delete() function explicitly and delete the memory at the end ??

```
class ST
{
 static ST* instance;
 ST(){};

private :

 static ST* getInstance();

};


ST* ST::instance = NULL;
ST* ST::getInstance()
{
   //lock on mutex
  if(NULL == instance)
  {
     instance = new ST();
  }

return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, memory will not be freed automatically.
Probably, if you want to free singleton memory, the best way in this case is to call [atexit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) with function, that frees singleton.
If you use C++11, the best way is to use Meyers singleton.

```
ST& ST::getInstance()
{
   static ST instance;
   return instance;
}
```

Comment: Now you just have to be careful not to access it after it's been destroyed. Singletons are best avoided in C++, even if you think you have a good use for the anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You create Singleton when you want there should be single instance of class, and that install will not die till end of application. So, you can delete it, because you have pointer, usually you will not.

So object will (should) persist till end of application.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the instance, you are going to want to have a static function that is used to delete the pointer and set it to NULL so that future calls to getInstance() will properly instantiate a new object.

the following would just create an infinite loop

```c++
ST~ST()
{ 
    delete instance; 
}
```

so we end up with the following

```c++
class ST
{
 static ST* getInstance();
 static void destroyInstance();

private :
 static ST* instance;
 ST(){};
 ~ST(){};

};


ST* ST::instance = NULL;
ST* ST::getInstance()
{
   //lock on mutex
  if(NULL == instance)
  {
     instance = new ST();
  }

return instance;
}

void ST::destroyInstance()
{
   //lock on mutex
  if(NULL == instance)
  {
     delete instance;
     instance = NULL;
  }
}
```